# Downsteam Demand Does Not Propagate Upstream After Encoutering SubscribeOn

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I have a `Spring` application that is triggered with an `ApplicationReadyEvent` as:

```
  @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
  public void poll() throws InterruptedException {
    Flux.just(1, 2, 3)
        .doOnNext(System.out::println)
        .log()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
        .log()
        .flatMap(Mono::just)
        .subscribe();
    System.out.println("Thread exiting: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    Thread.sleep(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
  }
```

Here are the logs:

```
{"timeStamp":"2021-04-21T15:16:31.288+05:30","message":"onSubscribe(FluxSubscribeOn.SubscribeOnSubscriber)","logger":"reactor.Flux.SubscribeOn.2","thread":"main","level":"INFO"}
{"timeStamp":"2021-04-21T15:16:31.289+05:30","message":"request(256)","logger":"reactor.Flux.SubscribeOn.2","thread":"main","level":"INFO"}
Thread exiting: main
```

The request does seem to propagate above `subscribeOn`. However, if I don't use `subscribeOn`, it appears to be working normally as expected.

```
  @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
  public void poll() throws InterruptedException {
    Flux.just(1, 2, 3)
        .doOnNext(System.out::println)
        .log()
        .flatMap(Mono::just)
        .subscribe();
    System.out.println("Thread exiting: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    Thread.sleep(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
  }
```

Logs:

```
{"timeStamp":"2021-04-21T15:20:35.370+05:30","message":"| onSubscribe([Fuseable] FluxPeekFuseable.PeekFuseableSubscriber)","logger":"reactor.Flux.PeekFuseable.1","thread":"main","level":"INFO"}
{"timeStamp":"2021-04-21T15:20:35.371+05:30","message":"| request(256)","logger":"reactor.Flux.PeekFuseable.1","thread":"main","level":"INFO"}
1
{"timeStamp":"2021-04-21T15:20:35.371+05:30","message":"| onNext(1)","logger":"reactor.Flux.PeekFuseable.1","thread":"main","level":"INFO"}
2
{"timeStamp":"2021-04-21T15:20:35.371+05:30","message":"| onNext(2)","logger":"reactor.Flux.PeekFuseable.1","thread":"main","level":"INFO"}
3
{"timeStamp":"2021-04-21T15:20:35.372+05:30","message":"| onNext(3)","logger":"reactor.Flux.PeekFuseable.1","thread":"main","level":"INFO"}
{"timeStamp":"2021-04-21T15:20:35.372+05:30","message":"| onComplete()","logger":"reactor.Flux.PeekFuseable.1","thread":"main","level":"INFO"}
Thread exiting: main
```

What is the reason behind such behaviour?

Comment: The operator `subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())` exchange the task to another thread. From (https://spring.io/blog/2019/12/13/flight-of-the-flux-3-hopping-threads-and-schedulers) `So the Thread on which the lambda is executed might be different from the subscription Thread , ie. the thread on which the subscribe method is called.`. I implemented and tested your code but I could not reproduce the same behavior. Maybe you have some log configuration that disable printing what does not come from the main thread?

Comment: It's not a problem with the log. The elements aren't emitted from the publisher as well as there is no demand. I'll try to reproduce this in a fresh Spring Boot application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was caused by a badly implemented forwarding `ScheduledExecutorService` class that I was using instead of Reactor's default service as:

```
Schedulers.addExecutorServiceDecorator(
        "forwardingScheduledExecutorService",
        (scheduler, scheduledExecutorService) ->
            new ForwardingScheduledExecutorService(scheduledExecutorService));
```

Comment: Indeed the problem was coming from other place